# How to find expectation and variance of the estimator interval censored binomial data

Tags: expectation, estimation, variance, maximum-likelihood

Suppose given a fixed number $n$, and a random binomial variable $X$ is only known to fall in the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers between $0$ and $n$.

I  have an estimator of  interval-censored binomial data
$$ \bar{x} = \dfrac{1}{(x_2-x_1+1)}⁡ \left( \sum_{i=x_1}^{x_2} \log \dfrac{\frac{i}{n}}{1-\frac{i}{n}}  \right)$$
where 
$0<x_1<x_2<n$.
How to find expectation and variance of the estimator?

Comment: Your $\tilde{x}$ is deterministic, so its expectation is itself and its variance is zero.